# Is typeid the same on different computers?

Tags: c++

I am wondering if `hash_code()` of typeid is the same on different computers? For an example: if `typeid(int).hash_code()` is it will be the same on another computer?

Comment: There are exactly 0 guarantees of that. They don’t even have to be the same on the same computer in two consecutive runs of the same binary. A very obvious implementation would be to hash a pointer address.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am wondering if `hash_code()` of typeid is the same on different computers?

It may or may not be.  From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code) the behavior is:

> Returns an unspecified value such that for all `type_info` objects referring to the same type, their `hash_code()` is the same.
>
> No other guarantees are given: `type_info` objects referring to different types may have the same `hash_code` (although the standard recommends that implementations avoid this as much as possible), and `hash_code` for the same type can change between invocations of the same program.

Answer (score 1):

From cppreference :

> hash_code for the same type can change between invocations of the same program

(cited from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code)).
So not only is it not guaranteed to be the same on different computers, it's not even guaranteed to be the same for the same program every time.